# will sharepoint 2013 support MVC

Tags: development, mvc

I'm wandering if anyone knows if SharePoint 2013 will support MVC. Does anyone know?

I'm wanting to be able to implement MVC in my sharepoint development process.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this post. Since SharePoint 2013 is built around the app model you have the option of using MVC4 MVC3 ASPX Web Forms or Silverlight. On SharePoint 2013 application pages or websites will not be integrated with the SharePoint Site as in 2010. You can read the below related post and see how you can do your mvc app.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevpreview/thread/35c4ae18-6ce0-4a9e-8c6b-6c730914c132